# How to create a function in Javascript which calls other functions

Tags: javascript

I have a task that I am trying to solve. I have created a function named printRange which will print the number range between rangeStart and rangeStop and all values separated by a comma.

```
var rangeStart, rangeStop;
function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
var numberRow = "";
for(var i=rangeStart; i <= rangeStop; i++) {
    numberRow += "," + i;
}
return numberRow;
}
```

I have also created another function named "printRangeReversed" which will print the range but in the opposite order. Again, the values will be separated by a comma.

```
function printRangeReversed(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
var numberRow = "";
for(var i=rangeStop; i >= rangeStart; i--) {
    numberRow += "," + i;
}
return numberRow;
}
```

Now I should create a new function called printAnyRange. If 'rangeStart' is smaller than 'rangeStop' then I should call the function 'printRange()'. If 'rangeStart' is greater than 'rangeStop' then I should call the function 'printRangeReversed()'.

How do I do this? I have tried myself with the code below but does not get any satisfying results... Thanks in advance!

```
function printAnyRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
var numberRow = "";
if(rangeStart < rangeStop) {
printRange();
}
else {
    printRangeReversed();
}
}
printAnyRange(24, 41);
```

Comment: You should pass the arguments when you call the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to supply the arguments to `printRange()` and `printRangeReversed()`.

Just change

```
if(rangeStart < rangeStop) {
    printRange();
}
else {
    printRangeReversed();
}
```

with

```
if(rangeStart < rangeStop) {
    printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop);
}
else {
    printRangeReversed(rangeStart, rangeStop);
}
```

and it should work.